# White space on the top of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios7

I am not sure why there is so much white space on the top of UIScrollView. If I switch the tabs and come back to this tab again then everything is okay. See the image below:

[image]

How can I fix that?

UPDATE:

The constraints on the first UILabel which is the description are shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The fix is to implement the following line of code after in the viewDidLoad;

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: this disables the scrolling !!!! any ideas how to fix this without disabling scrolling.